# Bluetooth barcode scanner iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

Hi To All of you friends;

I am trying to implement the Bluetooth bar code scanner App in iPhone . I have spent 5 to 6 hour searching on it but unfortunately i could not found any specific document or example about it. Please give me any link of tutorial or example in answer.

i am new in iPhone development so please help me in this issue.

please give me answer this question.

Comment: any one is there that give me answer of this question please .......

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

https://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Zebra Crossing is an open-source library that can help you accomplish the scanning and creating of QR codes.  However, you'll have to be more specific about the Bluetooth part.